# How can the optimization time of a Support Vector Machine with huge Data Set be reduced?

Tags: c++, machine-learning, svm, cross-validation, training-data

I have 30k samples to train my Support Vector Machine and also do Cross Validation which adds to the computational expense. Are there any techniques or rules of thumb to reduce computational costs, e.g. partitioning in a certain way or training only on a specific subset of the 30k samples?

My code is already fast but depending on the choice of kernel parameter, it takes a considerable amount of time to perform the optimization. How can I speed this up?

Comment: When I tried to use SVMs with relatively big datasets I found out that usage of stochastic gradient descent DRAMATICALLY increases the training speed. I suggest you to try it?

Comment: There is **a lot** missing, what **exactly** you are doing. Which kernels? Which SVM-algorithms? Dimension and sparsity of your data? Binary vs. Multiclass? If Multiclass: OvR, OvO direct-formulation and so on... SVM-learning in general is hard, especially for kernelized-SVM. Depending on the dimension/sparsity + class-targets, 30k samples could be possible with a good implementation (some CV-settings will be super-slow because of huge amount of support-vectors created). You could try increasing kernel-cache (to shift asympt. complexity). SGD-based SVM is fast, but not directly kernelized.

Comment: thank you guys. Well actually I am using a relevance vector machine for binary classification. The algorithm is based on this paper by M. Tipping [link](http://www.miketipping.com/papers/met-fastsbl.pdf) and already adresses the issue of large data sets. The actual optimization procedure therein relies on the maximization of the marginal likelihood of the hyperparameters and is thus very specific.

Comment: I.e. no sequential learning methods like stochastic gradient are applicable. Therefore I am mainly interested in advise regarding the partitioning of the cross validation sets for the estimation of the Gaussian Kernel Width. The ratio of positive to negative samples is about 3 to 1. Can I take a subset of the 30k samples to train and still capture the underlying characteristics of the data?I would for example train on 15k samples and validate on the other 15k or is that too bold? My samples have 14 features, i.e. dimension = 14 while the data is not sparse (not a single zero entry)

Comment: I'm not a big fan of RVMs and i think you should try classic SVMs (much more software; more different algorithmic approaches for many use-cases). In general, your RVM is also trained sequentially (EM-algorithm; which is also the weakness of this approach -> no global guarantees). Subsets, Partitioning and co. can't be evaluated without knowledge of the data! Imbalanced classes are in general not that great. I would down-sample the larger class as a first-step (at the cost of losing information).

Comment: thank you. What means downsampling in this regard?

Comment: I just wanted to recommend counting the target-distribution, e.g. 3:1. Then sample in regards to this as many samples as you like. If you sample without replacing (until you hit a limit; no more samples left), you will have a dataset of size (1+1)/4 = 2/4 = 1/2 of the original size (and threw only samples away of the overrepresented target-value). Of course it loses information, but the now balanced dataset could help many ML-approaches, especially SVMs.

Comment: thanks a ton sascha. Btw. do I have to introduce a bias vector in my Design Matrix at all costs or can it be omitted in general?